# CSS3 borders no edges in other words lines don't meet in the corner

Tags: css, border

This is a tough one. I want to cut the corners off. so the lines never meet at the corners.

At first I thought maybe I could add two divs nested inside and just have border-right and border-bottom divs, but that won't work. any Ideas would be helpful.

I have attached a image you can look at.

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:before` and `:after` :pseudo-elements.

```css
#container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222426;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 275px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.box:first-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 3%;
  background-color: #777777;
  width: 1px;
  height: 90%;
}
.box:nth-child(3):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 3%;
  background-color: #777777;
  width: 1px;
  height: 90%;
}
.box:first-child:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #777777;
  height: 1px;
  width: 90%;
}
.box:nth-child(2):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 1%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #777777;
  height: 1px;
  width: 91%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">Some Content</div
  ><div class="box">Some Content</div
  ><div class="box">Some Content</div
  ><div class="box">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it work only if I keep the ">" spaced down?

Comment: @veronicabollettino - I'm sorry, I totally missed your question. That is because if there is a whitespace between `>` and `<`, browser will render the content with a whitespace. Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/r5dpw9u1/2/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/r5dpw9u1/1/)